# Can't find ghostscript in NLTK?

Tags: python, environment-variables, ipython, nltk, ghostscript

I'm playing around with NLTK, when I try to use the chunk module

```
enter import nltk as nk
Sentence  = "Betty Botter bought some butter, but she said the butter is  bitter, I f I put it in my batter, it will make my batter bitter."
tokens = nk.word_tokenize(Sentence)
tagged = nk.pos_tag(tokens)
entities = nk.chunk.ne_chunk(tagged)
```

The code runs fine, when I type

```
>> entities
```

I get the following error message:

```
enter code here Out[2]: Tree('S', [Tree('PERSON', [('Betty', 'NNP')]), Tree('PERSON', [('Botter', 'NNP')]), ('bought', 'VBD'), ('some', 'DT'), ('butter', 'NN'), (',', ','), ('but', 'CC'), ('she', 'PRP'), ('said', 'VBD'), ('the', 'DT'), ('butter', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('bitter', 'JJ'), (',', ','), ('I', 'PRP'), ('f', 'VBP'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('put', 'VBD'), ('it', 'PRP'), ('in', 'IN'), ('my', 'PRP$'), ('batter', 'NN'), (',', ','), ('it', 'PRP'), ('will', 'MD'), ('make', 'VB'), ('my', 'PRP$'), ('batter', 'NN'), ('bitter', 'NN'), ('.', '.')])Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py", line 343, in __call__
return method()

File "C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\tree.py", line 726, in _repr_png_
subprocess.call([find_binary('gs', binary_names=['gswin32c.exe', 'gswin64c.exe'], env_vars=['PATH'], verbose=False)] +

File "C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 602, in find_binary
binary_names, url, verbose))

File "C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 596, in find_binary_iter
url, verbose):

File "C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 567, in find_file_iter
raise LookupError('\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (div, msg, div))

LookupError: 

===========================================================================
NLTK was unable to find the gs file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the PATH environment variable.
===========================================================================
```

According [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37160385/3967806), the solution is to install Ghostscript, since the chunker is trying to use it to display a parse tree, and is looking for one of 3 binaries:

```
file_names=['gs', 'gswin32c.exe', 'gswin64c.exe']
```

to use. 
But even though I installed ghostscript and I can now find the binary in a windows search, but I am still getting the same error.

What do I need to fix or update?

---

Additional path information:

```
import os; print os.environ['PATH']
```

Returns:

```
C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Library\bin;C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Library\bin;C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2;C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Library\bin;C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Library\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Parallels Tools\Applications;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Oracle\RPAS14.1\RpasServer\bin;C:\Oracle\RPAS14.1\RpasServer\applib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\jre\bin\client;C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2;C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Library\bin;
```

Comment: You might be missing the models. Try running `import nltk; nltk.download('all', halt_on_error=False)`. Then re-run your script.

Comment: @alvas that didn't fix it.

Comment: Where did you install ghostscript? Where is the ghostscript .exe file located?

Comment: Okay, now this is a little interesting =)

Comment: @alvas C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.19\bin

Comment: What is your output for `import os; print os.environ['PATH']`? Alternatively, you can also use `import os; print os.getenv('PATH')`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In short**:

Instead of `>>> entities`, do this:

```
>>> print entities.__repr__()
```

Or:

```
>>> import os
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
>>> path_to_gs = "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.19\bin"
>>> os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + path_to_gs
>>> sent = "Betty Botter bought some butter, but she said the butter is  bitter, I f I put it in my batter, it will make my batter bitter."
>>> entities = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)))
>>> entities
```

---

**In long**:

The problem lies in you trying to print the output of the `ne_chunk` and that will fire ghostscript to get the string and drawing representation of the NE tagged sentence, which is an `nltk.tree.Tree` object. And that will require ghostscript so you can use the widget to visualize it.

Let's walkthrough this step by step.

First when you use `ne_chunk`, you can directly import it at the top level as such:

```
from nltk import ne_chunk
```

And it's advisable to use namespaces for your imports, i.e.:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
```

And when you use `ne_chunk`, it comes from [https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/chunk/**init**.py](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/chunk/__init__.py)

It's unclear what kind of function is the pickle loading but after some inspection, we find that there's only one built-in NE chunker that isn't rule-based and since the name of the pickle binary states maxent, we can assume that it's a statistical chunker, so it most probably be comes from the `NEChunkParser` object in this: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/chunk/named_entity.py . There are ACE data API functions too, so as the name of the pickle binary.

Now, whenever you can the `ne_chunk` function, it's actually calling the
`NEChunkParser.parse()` function that returns a `nltk.tree.Tree` object: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/chunk/named_entity.py#L118

```
class NEChunkParser(ChunkParserI):
    """
    Expected input: list of pos-tagged words
    """
    def __init__(self, train):
        self._train(train)

    def parse(self, tokens):
        """
        Each token should be a pos-tagged word
        """
        tagged = self._tagger.tag(tokens)
        tree = self._tagged_to_parse(tagged)
        return tree

    def _train(self, corpus):
        # Convert to tagged sequence
        corpus = [self._parse_to_tagged(s) for s in corpus]

        self._tagger = NEChunkParserTagger(train=corpus)

    def _tagged_to_parse(self, tagged_tokens):
        """
        Convert a list of tagged tokens to a chunk-parse tree.
        """
        sent = Tree('S', [])

        for (tok,tag) in tagged_tokens:
            if tag == 'O':
                sent.append(tok)
            elif tag.startswith('B-'):
                sent.append(Tree(tag[2:], [tok]))
            elif tag.startswith('I-'):
                if (sent and isinstance(sent[-1], Tree) and
                    sent[-1].label() == tag[2:]):
                    sent[-1].append(tok)
                else:
                    sent.append(Tree(tag[2:], [tok]))
        return sent
```

If we take a look at the [`nltk.tree.Tree`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tree.py)ject that's where the ghostscript problems appears when it's trying to call the `_repr_png_` function: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tree.py#L702:

```
def _repr_png_(self):
    """
    Draws and outputs in PNG for ipython.
    PNG is used instead of PDF, since it can be displayed in the qt console and
    has wider browser support.
    """
    import os
    import base64
    import subprocess
    import tempfile
    from nltk.draw.tree import tree_to_treesegment
    from nltk.draw.util import CanvasFrame
    from nltk.internals import find_binary
    _canvas_frame = CanvasFrame()
    widget = tree_to_treesegment(_canvas_frame.canvas(), self)
    _canvas_frame.add_widget(widget)
    x, y, w, h = widget.bbox()
    # print_to_file uses scrollregion to set the width and height of the pdf.
    _canvas_frame.canvas()['scrollregion'] = (0, 0, w, h)
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as file:
        in_path = '{0:}.ps'.format(file.name)
        out_path = '{0:}.png'.format(file.name)
        _canvas_frame.print_to_file(in_path)
        _canvas_frame.destroy_widget(widget)
        subprocess.call([find_binary('gs', binary_names=['gswin32c.exe', 'gswin64c.exe'], env_vars=['PATH'], verbose=False)] +
                        '-q -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=png16m -r90 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sOutputFile={0:} {1:}'
                        .format(out_path, in_path).split())
        with open(out_path, 'rb') as sr:
            res = sr.read()
        os.remove(in_path)
        os.remove(out_path)
        return base64.b64encode(res).decode()
```

But note that it's strange that the python interpreter would fire `_repr_png` instead of `__repr__` when you use `>>> entities` at the interpreter (see [Purpose of Python's __repr__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr)). It couldn't be how the native CPython interpreter work when trying to print out the representation of an object, so we take a look at `Ipython.core.formatters` and we see that it allows `_repr_png` to be fired at https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/formatters.py#L725:

```
class PNGFormatter(BaseFormatter):
    """A PNG formatter.
    To define the callables that compute the PNG representation of your
    objects, define a :meth:`_repr_png_` method or use the :meth:`for_type`
    or :meth:`for_type_by_name` methods to register functions that handle
    this.
    The return value of this formatter should be raw PNG data, *not*
    base64 encoded.
    """
    format_type = Unicode('image/png')

    print_method = ObjectName('_repr_png_')

    _return_type = (bytes, unicode_type)
```

And we see that when IPython initializes a `DisplayFormatter` object, it tries to activate all formatters: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/formatters.py#L66

```
def _formatters_default(self):
    """Activate the default formatters."""
    formatter_classes = [
        PlainTextFormatter,
        HTMLFormatter,
        MarkdownFormatter,
        SVGFormatter,
        PNGFormatter,
        PDFFormatter,
        JPEGFormatter,
        LatexFormatter,
        JSONFormatter,
        JavascriptFormatter
    ]
    d = {}
    for cls in formatter_classes:
        f = cls(parent=self)
        d[f.format_type] = f
    return d
```

Note that outside of `Ipython`, in the native CPython interpreter, it will only call the `__repr__` and not the `_repr_png`:

```
>>> from nltk import ne_chunk
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
>>> Sentence  = "Betty Botter bought some butter, but she said the butter is  bitter, I f I put it in my batter, it will make my batter bitter."
>>> sentence  = "Betty Botter bought some butter, but she said the butter is  bitter, I f I put it in my batter, it will make my batter bitter."
>>> entities = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence)))
>>> entities
Tree('S', [Tree('PERSON', [('Betty', 'NNP')]), Tree('PERSON', [('Botter', 'NNP')]), ('bought', 'VBD'), ('some', 'DT'), ('butter', 'NN'), (',', ','), ('but', 'CC'), ('she', 'PRP'), ('said', 'VBD'), ('the', 'DT'), ('butter', 'NN'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('bitter', 'JJ'), (',', ','), ('I', 'PRP'), ('f', 'VBP'), ('I', 'PRP'), ('put', 'VBD'), ('it', 'PRP'), ('in', 'IN'), ('my', 'PRP$'), ('batter', 'NN'), (',', ','), ('it', 'PRP'), ('will', 'MD'), ('make', 'VB'), ('my', 'PRP$'), ('batter', 'NN'), ('bitter', 'NN'), ('.', '.')])
```

---

So now the solution:

**Solution 1**:

When printing out the string output of the `ne_chunk`, you can use

```
>>> print entities.__repr__()
```

instead of `>>> entities` that way, IPython should explicitly call only the `__repr__` instead of call all possible formatters.

**Solution 2**

If you really need to use the `_repr_png_` to visualize the Tree object, then we will need to figure out how to add the ghostscript binary to the NLTK environmental variables.

In your case, it seems like the default `nltk.internals` are unable to find the binary. More specifically, we're referring to https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/internals.py#L599

If we go back to https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tree.py#L726, we see that, it's trying to look for the

```
env_vars=['PATH']
```

And when NLTK tries to initialize it's environment variables, it is looking at `os.environ`, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/internals.py#L495

Note that `find_binary` calls `find_binary_iter` which calls `find_binary_iter` that tries to look for the `env_vars` by fetching `os.environ`

So if we add to the path:

```
>>> import os
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
>>> path_to_gs = "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.19\bin"
>>> os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + path_to_gs
```

Now this should work in Ipython:

```
>>> import os
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
>>> path_to_gs = "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.19\bin"
>>> os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + path_to_gs
>>> sent = "Betty Botter bought some butter, but she said the butter is  bitter, I f I put it in my batter, it will make my batter bitter."
>>> entities = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)))
>>> entities
```

Comment: Worked after I changed the forward slashes to back slashes in the path_to_gs assignment. Thanks

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the outputs to `os.environ['PATH']`? That will be helpful in the future if someone else have the same problem =) Thanks!

Comment: As @predictorx mentions below, "\b" can be mapped to "\x08", to avoid that, either escape every backslashes (replacing `"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.19\bin"` by `"C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.19\\bin"`) or use forward slash `/` in the path. And more generally,  in Windows, add that path in the user's`Path` Environment Variable to avoid these lines in each script.

Answer (score 1):

Download `gs.exe` from "https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html" and add its path to `Environment Variables`

Path may be stored at

> C:\Program Files\
>
> (in my system it looks like "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.21\bin")

and for adding it to environment variable:

> control panel->system and security->system->advanced system
>   settings->Environment Variables->(in system variables scroll down and
>   double click on path)->

and then add the copied path

> (in my case "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.21\bin")

**P.S.**: Don't forget to add semicolon (`;`) before coping the path instead of deleting the existing paths and then simply putting it there, you might get into trouble and would need to run backup :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I add path with same code of alvas, it turns out:

```
'C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs9.27\x08in'
```

Which is not correct, so, I change to: path_to_gs = 'C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.27/bin' and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the comment of @predictorx.  What worked for me is

```
    path_to_gs = "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.53.3\\bin"
    os.environ['PATH'] += path_to_gs
```